# Ошибки с mysql при переходе на php7- как исправить?

Tags: php7, php5

CMS написана на php5 
Сейчас стоит PHP-7 64
Apache -PHP-7 64
MySQL 5.5

Пробую переписать запросы из mysql в mysqli, но не везде срабатывает, выдаёт ошибки:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in 32

т.е. это в стр.

```
$res = mysqli_query($cid,$query);
```

функция полностью:

```
public function get_all_db() {
    $sql = "SELECT id,title,discription FROM statti LIMIT 10";

    $res = mysqli_query($cid,$query);

    if(!$res) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    for ($i = 0;$i < mysqli_num_rows($res); $i++) {
        $row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC);
    }

    return $row;
}
```

та же ошибка с mysql в `public function get_one_db($id)`

Код полностью:

```
<?php

class Database {
    public $db;

    public function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$db) {
        //$this->db = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

        /*$this->db = mysqli_connect(‘host’, $user, $pass, $db)

         or die('Ошибка соединения с БД');*/

        $this->db = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'my_bd') or die('Ошибка соединения с БД');

        /*if(!$this->db) {
            exit('No connection with database');
        }
        if(!mysql_select_db($db,$this->db)) {
            exit('No table');
        }*/

        //mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");
    //  mysqli_query($link, ‘set names cp1251’)
        /*mysqli_set_charset($db, "utf8") or die('Не установлена кодировка');*/

        return $this->db;
    }

    public function get_all_db() {
        $sql = "SELECT id,title,discription FROM statti LIMIT 10";

        $res = mysqli_query($cid,$query);

        if(!$res) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        for ($i = 0;$i < mysqli_num_rows($res); $i++) {
            $row[] = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC);
        }

        return $row;
    }

    public function get_one_db($id) {

        $sql = "SELECT id,title,text FROM statti WHERE id='$id'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);

        if(!$res) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC);

        return $row;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Ошибка вам говорит, что 1 параметром приходит `null`, что не может быть в реалиях. - скорее где-то не до заменили, или пытается от `mysql_connect` влететь в `mysqli_query`, что тоже недопустимо.

Answer (score 0):

`$res = mysqli_query($cid,$query);` Кто такой `$cid`? Он у вас в коде нигде не объявляется, но используется.

Так не нужно делать

```
public $db;
...
$sql = "SELECT id,title,text FROM statti WHERE id='$id'";
```

Так можно

```
private $db; // или protected $db;
...
$sql = "SELECT id,title,text FROM statti WHERE id=?";
```

Модуль mysql не просто так выключили. Прочитайте про подготовленные запросы.

Comment: `Модуль mysql не просто так выключили` - никто его не выключал, он был удален полностью..